# Coroutine as dependency to useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Current I have the following custom hook:

```
function useSecurity() {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0()

  const getAccessToken = async () => {
    return await getAccessTokenSilently()
  }
  
  const getAuthHeader = async () => {
    return { Authorization: `Bearer ${await getAccessToken()}` }
  }
   
  return { getAuthHeader }
}
```

In a page where I use it I have:

```
const { getAuthHeader } = useSecurity()

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    ...
    }
  }
  fetchData()
}, [getAuthHeader])
```

This code causes infinite loop page load, I assume because getAuthHeader is a coroutine. I know I can don't have to include it in the deps (and ignore eslint warnings), but is there a way I can include it in the deps and not trigger the infinite loop?

Comment: Seems no-one is taking this one... You need to be prepared for your render function to be called multiple times. At the moment it looks like you're making that fetchData request on every single render. I suspect there is code in there (that you haven't shown) that might be triggering a re-render. RE: your original question, you need to wrap your getAuthHeader function in useCallback so it doesn't change reference every time the hook is called. Depending on how useAuth0 works you might be able to get away with using that in the deps array.

Comment: Ahhh, great. Thanks, that worked. I'll add the answer below for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `getAuthHeader` is used like a hook, but it's actually async method. You can try setting it up like this:

```
function useSecurity() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    getToken = async () => {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
      setToken(token)
    }

    getToken();
  }, []);
   
  return { token }
}
```

This was you'd have the token stored in state of `useSecurity` hook and then just use it like this:

```
const { token } = useSecurity()

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    ...
    }
  }
  fetchData()
}, [token])
```

Comment: This doesn't work since it creates a race condition: Since getToken in useSecurity is async, token isn't set before useEffect in the code which uses the hook runs.

Comment: @pondermatic I know but you can't await in your react component because it's not how it works - if you want to handle that scenario correctly then you have to show loading state while token is loaded.

Comment: See my answer above. Using useCallback fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Using david's suggestion to use useCallback() fixes the issue. The working code is:

```
function useSecurity() {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0()

  const getAccessToken = async () => {
    return await getAccessTokenSilently()
  }
  
  const getAuthHeader = async () => {
    return { Authorization: `Bearer ${await getAccessToken()}` }
  }
   
  return { getAuthHeader: useCallback(getAuthHeader, []) }
}
```